# SQLite join with converse implication

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, A and B:

```
A.id
A.name

B.id
B.A_id <-- points to A in a many to one relationship
B.tag <-- predefined integer
```

I need to join the two such that:

```
SELECT A.name, B.name, B.tag FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id 
WHERE (B.tag IN (1,2,3) AND B.tag NOT IN (4,5)
```

and the resulting return needs to be such that it will return all A and B returned are in **1, 2, 3** only and NOT IN **4, 5**.

If any of the A join returned contain a B.tag that has an excluded tag, then we should not see it being returned, even if there exists an A join with a valid B.tag.

i.e.

```
A.name = 'Bob'
A.id = 1


B.id = 1
B.A_id = 1
B.tag = 10


B.id = 2
B.A_id = 1
B.tag = 11


B.id = 3
B.A_id = 1
B.tag = 12
```

When we perform the query:

```
SELECT A.id, B.id, B.tag FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id 
WHERE (B.tag IN (10) AND B.tag NOT IN (11)
```

This will NOT return anything as we have the `NOT IN (11)` exclusion. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

I find your explanation a bit hard to follow.  I think you want `not exists`:

```
SELECT A.name, B.name, B.tag
FROM A INNER JOIN
     B
     ON A.id = B.a_id 
WHERE B.tag IN (1, 2, 3) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM B B2 
                  WHERE B2.a_id = A.id AND B2.tag IN (4, 5)
                 );
```